# Como usar el GROUP BY con sentencias CASE y funciones de agregación en consulta SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

tengo la siguiente consulta en donde estoy seleccionando el numero de cliente, hago uns CASE donde tengo los datos de medidas da la locacion y la suma del valor neto de la factura en una funcion SUM. Estos datos los llamo de una tabla de datos de la facturas.

El problema ocurre con la funcion SUM cuando trato de correr la consulta me da el siguiente error:

**00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"
*Cause:

*Action:
Error en fila: 18 Columna: 6**

He buscado en internet una solucion y en muchos casos leo que debo dejar fuera del GROUP BY el campo de agregacion en este caso SUM (fac_neto) pero para los otros dos campos CLT_NOMBRE1 y el de CASE (MELO) los debo incluir alli. En el caso de CASE toda la sentencia completa sin el alias. Lo he probado pero no me funciona. Alguien podria decirme que puede estar fallando, llevo varios dias tratando de solucionarlo pero sin exito.

```
SELECT CLT_NOMBRE1, --nombre del cliente 

(CASE WHEN zpk IS NULL 
THEN MAX (zpk) OVER(PARTITION BY factura_ha, facturanumero, locacion)
ELSE zpk END)MELO, -- Locacion de medida

SUM (fct_neto) fct_neto

FROM tbl_facturas
WHERE NETOZ !=0 
                AND lugar_lectura = '902'
                AND anio =  '2023'
GROUP BY CLT_NOMBRE1,
CASE WHEN zpk IS NULL 
THEN MAX (zpk) OVER(PARTITION BY re_ha, facturanumero, locacion) ELSE zpk END
```

Comment: Creo que sería bueno que agregaras un ejemplo básico de la tabla y un resultado esperado.

Comment: Difícil contestar sin conocer la relación -y cardinalidad- entre clt_nombre1, zpk, factura_ha, facturanumero, location). Parece que quieres combinar dos particiones sin relación alguna, en tal caso mejor basa tu consulta en el cliente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado realizando una subconsulta debido a que las funciones analíticas se evalúan después de las funciones de agregación. Es necesario utilizar una subconsulta para forzar la inversión del orden de evaluación.

```
SELECT CLT_NOMBRE1,
       melo,
       SUM(fct_neto) AS fct_neto
FROM   (
  SELECT CLT_NOMBRE1,
         CASE
         WHEN zpk IS NULL
         THEN MAX(zpk) OVER (PARTITION BY factura_ha, facturanumero,locacion)
         ELSE NULL
         END as MELO,
         fct_neto
  FROM   tbl_facturas
  WHERE  NETOZ !=0 
  AND    lugar_lectura = '902'
  AND    anio =  '2023'
)
GROUP BY
       CLT_NOMBRE1,
       melo;
```

La respuesta la pueden ver en el Stack Flow en ingles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76799645/query-with-sum-and-decode-and-other-columns-error-by-group-by/76799733#76799733

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu respuesta para mostrar cómo quedó finalmente tu consulta? Luego, no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: @padaleiana, la puedo tomar como mejor respuesta hasta mañana :)

Comment: Sí, por eso lo del tiempo mínimo :)